# Python ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am carrying out a API search on scaleserp and for each search I do i want to put the output in the column in my dataframe.

```
#Matches the GET request
api_result = requests.get('https://api.scaleserp.com/search', params, verify=False)
print(type(api_result))
#stores the result in JSON
result = api_result.json()
print(type(result))
#Creates a new DataFrame with 'Organic_Results' From the JSON output. 
Results_df = (result['organic_results'])
#FOR loop to look at each result and select which output from the JSON is wanted. 
for res in Results_df:
    StartingDataFrame['JSONDump'] = res
```

api_result is a requests.models.Response
result is a dict.
RES is a dict.
I want the RES to be put into the column Dump. is this possible?

Updated Code

```
 #Matches the GET request
api_result = requests.get('https://api.scaleserp.com/search', params, verify=False)
#stores the result in JSON
result = api_result.json()
#Creates a new DataFrame with 'Organic_Results' From the JSON output. 
Results_df = (result['organic_results'])

#FOR loop to look at each result and select which output from the JSON is wanted. 
for res in Results_df:
    Extracted_data = {key: res[key] for key in res.keys() 
                           & {'title', 'link', 'snippet_matched', 'date', 'snippet'}}
```

Extracted_data is a dict and contains the info i need.

```
{'title': '25 Jun 1914 - Advertising - Trove', 'link': 'https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/7280119', 'snippet_matched': ['()', 'charge', 'Dan Whit'], 'snippet': 'I Iron roof, riltibcd II (),. Line 0.139.5. wai at r ar ... Propertb-« entired free of charge. Line 2.130.0 ... AT Dan Whit",\'»\', 6il 02 sturt »L, Prlnce\'»~Brti\'»e,. Line 3.12.0.'}
{'snippet': "Mary Bardwell is in charge of ... I() •. Al'companit'd by: Choppf'd Chitkf'n Li\\f>r Palt·. 1h!iiSC'o Gret'n Salad g iii ... of the overtime as Dan Whit-.", 'title': 'October 16,1980 - Bethlehem Public Library', 
'link': 'http://www.bethlehempubliclibrary.org/webapps/spotlight/years/1980/1980-10-16.pdf', 'snippet_matched': ['charge', '()', 'Dan Whit'], 'date': '16 Oct 1980'}
{'snippet': 'CONGRATULATIONS TO DAN WHIT-. TLE ON THE ... jailed and beaten dozens of times. In one of ... ern p()rts ceased. The MIF is not only\xa0...', 'title': 'extensions of remarks - US Government Publishing Office', 'link': 'https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/GPO-CRECB-1996-pt5/pdf/GPO-CRECB-1996-pt5-7-3.pdf', 'snippet_matched': ['DAN WHIT', 'jailed', '()'], 'date': '26 Apr 1986'}
{'snippet': 'ILLUSTRATION BY DAN WHIT! By Matt Manning ... ()n the one hand, there are doctors on both ... self-serving will go to jail at the beginning of\xa0...', 'title': 'The BG News May 23, 2007 - ScholarWorks@BGSU - Bowling ...', 'link': 'https://scholarworks.bgsu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=8766&context=bg-news', 'snippet_matched': ['DAN WHIT', '()', 'jail'], 'date': '23 May 2007'}
{'snippet': '$19.95 Charge card number SERVICE HOURS: ... Explorer Advisor Dan Whit- ... lhrr %(OnrwflC or ()utuflrueonlinelfmarketing (arnpaigfl%? 0I - .', 
'title': '<%BANNER%> TABLE OF CONTENTS HIDE Section A: Main ...', 'link': 'https://ufdc.ufl.edu/UF00028295/00194', 'snippet_matched': ['Charge', 'Dan Whit', '()'], 'date': 'Listings 1 - 800'}
{'title': 'Lledo Promotional,Bull Nose Morris,Dandy,Desperate Dan ...', 'link': 'https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Lledo-Promotional-Bull-Nose-Morris-Dandy-Desperate-Dan-White-Van-/233817683840', 'snippet_matched': ['charges'], 'snippet': 'No additional import charges on delivery. This item will be sent through the Global Shipping Programme and includes international tracking. Learn more- opens\xa0...'}
```

Comment: Apologies just updated. it was inside of the for loop i needed to put it.

Comment: no sorry somebody wrote a question which i answered and realised i put the wrong code up. It has now been edited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like the length of your organic_results is not the same as the length of your dataframe.

```
StartingDataFrame['Dump'] = (result['organic_results'])
```

Here your setting the whole column dump to equal the organic_results which is smaller or larger than your already defined dataframe. I'm not sure what your dataframe already has but you could do this by iterating through the rows and stashing them in that row if you have values you want them to add up with like this:

```
StartingDataFrame['Dump'] = []*len(StartingDataFrame)
for i,row in StartingDataFrame.iterrows():
    StartingDataFrame.at[i,'Dump'] = result['organic_results']
```

Depending on what your data looks like you could maybe just append it to the dataframe

```
StartingDataFrame = StartingDataFrame.append(result['organic_results'],ignore_index=True)
```

Could you show us a sample of what both data source looks like?

Comment: So are you trying to get the dictionary as a data frame or is it just that data as rows? You can write dictionaries as a data frame by simply using.   pd.DataFrame(Extracted_Data,index=[0])